# bootstrap modal show with cookie set for 1 day

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, cookies

I have a bootstrap modal on a Wordpress site that I would like to appear only once every 24 hours.

I thought I had it, but this isn't working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($.cookie('show') == null) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $.cookie('show', { expires: 1 });
  }
});
```

This only shows once and then never again. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($.cookie('pop') == null) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $.cookie('pop', '1');
  }
});
```

It would seem that originally my expires: 1 was wrong.