# bootstrap modal show with cookie set for 30 min

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cookies, bootstrap-modal

I was following the steps in this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31834677/bootstrap-modal-show-with-cookie-set-for-1-day), and set up my cookie below to show my Modal once a day.

```
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#myModal').appendTo("body");

  if ($.cookie("pop") == null) {
      $("#myModal").modal("show");

      $.cookie("pop", ’1′);
  }

  $('#myModal').modal({
      keyboard: false,
      backdrop:false
  });});</script>
```

This works fine, but how do I set this up so that the cookie only last 30 minutes instead of one day?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass in an object with expires as a key, the value of that will be the expire date of the cookie in days.

ie:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000));
$.cookie("cookieName", "cookieValue", { expires: date });
```

this example would set the cookie to 30 minutes from the time of creation

Comment: Thank you @jay I'm going to give this a try and test it out.